# replace images with links from external txt file

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a function that I use to replace players avatars with custom images. So far I've got 3 of them and have built the static replacement links into a Chrome extension. What I'd like to do instead is have the function look at an external txt file to build an array so I can add new players without having the republish the extension every time. I can just add new link pairs to the text file.

The external replacer.txt file is:

```
{
  "replaced": [
    {
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png"
    },
    {
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/ZXGinstead.png"
    },
    {
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/skelinstead.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

The function that's part of my Chrome extension is:

```
$.getJSON('https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/replacer.txt', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function () {
            $('a.avatarContainer img').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(data.replaced.original[0], data.replaced.newone[0]));
            });
        });
    });
```

This just generates a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in the console.

The function that worked was

```
    $('a.avatarContainer img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png", "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png"));
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png", "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/ZXGinstead.png"));
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png", "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/skelinstead.png"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your index in the wrong place

This will find the image to replace:

```js
const dataString = `{
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png",
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/ZXGinstead.png",
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/skelinstead.png"
}` // the data in backticks is what the file looks like

const data = JSON.parse(dataString); // this is what getJSON does for you

$('a.avatarContainer img').each(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src"), replace = data[src];
  if (replace) $(this).attr("src", replace);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png" /></a>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png" /></a>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png" /></a>
```

And this is more like your original code but I am not sure it is what you really wanted

```js
const data = {
  "replaced": [{
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png"
    },
    {
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/ZXGinstead.png"
    },
    {
      "original": "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png",
      "newone": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/skelinstead.png"
    }
  ]
}

$.each(data, function() {
  $('a.avatarContainer img').each(function(i,img) {
    var $img = $(img);
    $img.attr('src', data.replaced[i].newone)
   // simpler than 
   // var src = $img.attr('src');
   // $img.attr('src', src.replace(data.replaced[i].original, data.replaced[i].newone));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png" /></a>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png" /></a>
<a class="avatarContainer"><img src="/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png" /></a>
```

Comment: That almost works but, the images being replaced are on pages where there are others not needing to be replaced. I need the specific old image to be replaced with the matching new image. The code you provided (thank you!) replaces the first 3 instances of a.avatarContainer img regardless of what they were originally.

Comment: Your first example doesn't generate any errors in the Chrome dev console and it clearly works if I run the Code Snippet but, when I try to use the code in my extension it doesn't have any result. I wrapped it in a getJSON query referencing the external file otherwise how will it know what's in it?

Comment: My first example needs your text file to be changed to reflect the key/value I use: `{
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1115_836_937_952_856_1100_904_875_863_922_840_503.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/FJinstead.png",
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/15_140_118_1168_1519_574_306_982_181_125.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/ZXGinstead.png",
  "/imgs/avatar/generated/26_1114_1452_1115_2092_925_1102_847_914_1126_967_1125_871_2082_2080.png": "https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/skelinstead.png"
}`

Comment: Also does your extension have the rights to access the file? It may also have to be `JSON.parse`d

Comment: I saw the text file was different and tried it with your version. The extension does have access to the file (that came up early in this idea  :-)  ).

Comment: ```$.getJSON('https://cbsargecom.ipage.com/imgs/replacer.txt', function (data) {
        $('a.avatarContainer img').each(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src"), replace = data[src];
  if (replace) $(this).attr("src", replace);
});
    });
```

Comment: Your file needs to be without `const data =`

Comment: I changed the replacer.txt file to not include the const data = part but, I'm still not clear on how the function will know how to get to the txt file to parse it? It's on an external server. I probably should have mentioned that at the beginning.

Comment: I emailed you the 2 files.

Comment: I did not receive anything as of yet